# Writing multiple lat, lon points as path to a KML file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, kml

I am trying to write/export a series of latitude and longitude points as the path followed by a vehicle to a KML file in MATLAB. The following command seems to be accepting one pair of lat,lon only.

```
clc
format long g
lat1=33.642956; 
lon1=72.991585;
lat2=33.643051;
lon2=72.991282;
lat3=33.643190;
lon3=72.990963;
lat4=33.643310;
lon4=72.990690;
filename = 'MathWorks.kml';
kmlwriteline(filename,lat1,lon1);
```

The desired output is writting all the lat,lon to the KML file but the command `kmlwriteline(filename,lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,lat3,lon3,lat4,lon4,);`
returns error.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/kmlwriteline.html)  `lat` and `lon` need to be vectors of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

All `lat` and all `lon` values need to be put in a vector

```
lat1=33.642956; 
lon1=72.991585;
lat2=33.643051;
lon2=72.991282;
lat3=33.643190;
lon3=72.990963;
lat4=33.643310;
lon4=72.990690;

lats = [lat1 lat2 lat3 lat4];
lons = [lon1 lon2 lon3 lon4];
filename = 'MathWorks.kml';
kmlwriteline(filename,lats,lons);
```